# SSTP VPN connection fails after updating / removing an IIS certificate

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-7, sstp

After I removed / updated an IIS certificate, I am unable to maintain an SSTP VPN connection with the server. As far as I recall the certificate was NOT used for authentication. Users authenticate with a username and password.

The VPN connection is created successfully but as soon as it is reached, client is disconnected.
Information from log on both the server and client.

**Client:**

> CoId={45DF11CA-BE9C-44A0-8EB2-E47DDA5D4220}: The user XXXX\YYY dialed a connection named CCCCC which has terminated. The reason code returned on termination is 829.

**And on the server:**

```
The description for Event ID 440 from source NPS cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your locla computer or the installation is corrupted. (...)
```

ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the same certificate was used by Routing and Remote Access not for authentication but for maintaining secure TLS connection.

Solution: Go to Routing and Remote Access snap-in, right-click on the properties of your router (MACHINE-NAME (local) properties in the tree-view to the left) select the Security Tab; you will be warned that there's no TLS certificate selected (the previous has expired in my case) and select the new one at the bottom.